# services.AddLogging() prevent NLog logger running?

Tags: c#, .net-core, nlog

I have the following .net core 2.0 code and the NLog is not output anything.

```
private static IServiceProvider BuildDi()
{
    var services = new ServiceCollection();

    services.AddTransient<Runner>();

    services.AddSingleton<ILoggerFactory, LoggerFactory>();
    services.AddSingleton(typeof(ILogger<>), typeof(Logger<>));
    services.AddLogging((builder) => builder.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace));

    var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

    var loggerFactory = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>();

    //configure NLog
    loggerFactory.AddNLog(new NLogProviderOptions { CaptureMessageTemplates = true, CaptureMessageProperties = true });
    NLog.LogManager.LoadConfiguration("nlog.config");

    return serviceProvider;
}
```

And it starts to output after the following line is removed?

```
services.AddLogging((builder) => builder.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace));
```

What is `AddLogging` for?

Comment: Show an example the logging calls that did not work

Comment: `_logger.Info(”....")`

Comment: Is that accurate? I thought the extension method was `LogInformation`

Comment: I'm traveling now and didn't remember the exactly syntax. But it's working now after I remove the services.AddLogging().

Answer (score 2):

[`AddLogging`](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/release/2.0/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging/LoggingServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L32)  basically does exactly what the two lines above it does in your original example.

And the delegate is used to configure the log builder.

In this case the minimum log level is trace.

If lets say it was set to `Information` the it would have ignored `Trace` and `Debug` logs.

The following should provide the same desired functionality if using .net core 2.0

```
private static IServiceProvider BuildDi() {
    var services = new ServiceCollection();

    services.AddTransient<Runner>();

    // Adds logging services to the service collection
    // If you don't explicitly set the minimum level, the default value is 
    // Information, which means that Trace and Debug logs are ignored.
    services.AddLogging();

    var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

    var loggerFactory = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>();

    /// Enable NLog as logging provider in .NET Core.
    loggerFactory.AddNLog(new NLogProviderOptions { CaptureMessageTemplates = true, CaptureMessageProperties = true });
    // Apply NLog configuration from XML config.
    loggerFactory.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config");

    return serviceProvider;
}
```